# How to read image data as a 2D grid using gnuplot

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, grayscale

Gnuplot is a very powerful library that supports plotting of functions with numerous scientific operations. What my case is I want to read a single channel grayscale image just as we read in matlab or python using `imread` and store it into a 2D data grid using gnuPlot.

Basically I want to make contours of image gray scale intensities.To do that I am exporting the single channel luminance  data of the image as a `.dat` file using matlab once it is exported I splot it using:

```
set contour base 
splot 'greyScaleImagePixelByPixelData.dat' matrix
```

This works fine but in case I dont want to use Matlab to export the pixel by pixel data to surface plot the image what is the way around?

Comment: What format is this image?  Gnuplot can read a few image types natively (avs edf ehf gif jpeg png).  Other formats might be possible but would require knowing more about the exact data format.

Comment: It is a png or a jpg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below has been tested with 8-bit and 16-bit grayscale png images (no alpha channel).  If your particular images do not match this, please provide a more complete description of how they are encoded.

You haven't said exactly what you want to do with the pixel data after reading it in, so I show the obvious example of displaying it as an image (e.g. a regular array of pixels).  If you want to do further manipulation of the values before plotting, please expand the question to give additional details.

```
[~/temp] file galaxy-16bitgrayscale.png
galaxy-16bitgrayscale.png: PNG image data, 580 x 363, 16-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
[~/temp] gnuplot
set autoscale noextend
plot 'galaxy-16bitgrayscale.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage
```

Note that gnuplot does not have any separate storage mode for grayscale vs. RGB image data.  In this case it loads 3 copies of each 16-bit grayscale value into parallel storage as if it were separate R/G/B pixel data.

[image]

**[2nd edit: show both grayscale image and contour levels]**

```
set autoscale noextend
set view map
set contour surface
set cntrparam levels discrete 100, 200
set cntrparam firstlinetype 1
set key outside title "Contour levels"
splot 'galaxy16bit.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage notitle, \
      '' binary filetype=png with lines nosurface title ""
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question to include more details. Please note that my image pixel by pixel data is between 0 to 1

Comment: Both PNG and JPEG files contain integer data, not floating point numbers between 0 and 1.  Do you want gnuplot to read the original PNG or JPEG file, or do you want it to read some other format file that contains floating point values?

Comment: I actually tried different permutations. Yes I also tried with your answer and it works good. I also tried reading a file containg floating point numbers and it also works. But I am stuck at a point and that is do you know of any way that we can plot the contours as displayed in your answer over the grayscale image? I tried to even do it using 'set table <table.dat>' but in that way I wasn't able to set the key

Comment: I know it is unrelated to the question but I can achieve exactly what I want if I can divide my Key values with a constant and then display. Is this possible?

Comment: Replace `title ""` with `notitle` for the contour plot and then add your desired key entries manually using extra clauses like `keyentry with lines lt 1 title "Contour at my first value"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess in this case there is now no way we can use contour auto levels. Because we wont be able to get the contour level that is auto calculated right? Can we get the contour levels generated automatically by gnuplot?

Comment: This scenario is getting too complicated for a comment thread.  Also it is no longer about image data. Please ask again as a new question about auto-generated contour levels and custom labels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597326/get-the-contour-levels-that-are-auto-generated-using-gnu-plot-contour-function