# Get the contour levels that are auto generated using gnu plot contour function

Tags: gnuplot

I know how to generate contours of an image file using gnuplot.

```
set autoscale noextend
set view map
set contour surface
set cntrparam levels 15
set key outside title "Contour levels"
splot 'sampleImage.png' binary filetype=png with lines nosurface title ""
```

The contours are plotted over the image with respect to a maximum of 255, like at 255, 250, 245 etc. How can I read these key values in gnuplot?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample image?

Comment: Please take any any smooth image as a sample. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482486/how-to-read-image-data-as-a-2d-grid-using-gnuplot/66487075#comment117697143_66487075

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, the following code puts both the greyscale values and the contour values into tables. There you find all information.

**Input:** (`Input.png`)

[image]

**Code:**

```
### get greyscale pixel data and contour data
reset session

FILE = 'Input.png'

set view map
set size square
set tics out

set table $Dummy
    set contour
    splot FILE binary filetype=png
    unset contour
set table $Data
    plot $Dummy u 1:2:3 index 0 w table
set table $Contour
    plot $Dummy u 1:2:3 index 1::1 w table
unset table

# print a few grey values
print sprintf("Number of data points:    %d",|$Data|)
do for [i=1:40000:2500] { print $Data[i] }

# print a few contour values
print sprintf("Number of contour points: %d",|$Contour|)
do for [i=700:710] { print $Contour[i] }

set multiplot layout 1,2
    set autoscale noextend
    splot FILE binary filetype=png  with rgbimage notitle

    set key outside title "Contour levels"
    set contour surface
    set cntrparam levels 15
    splot FILE binary filetype=png with lines nosurface title ""
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:** (just a few excerpt of the tables)

```
Number of data points:    40000
 0       0       4
 100     12      46
 0       25      4
 100     37      152
 0       50      6
 100     62      168
 0       75      19
 100     87      165
 0       100     30
 100     112     186
 0       125     31
 100     137     171
 0       150     22
 100     162     127
 0       175     11
 100     187     70

Number of contour points: 1328
 54.5    163     100
 55      163.5   100
 56      164     100
 110     20      100
 109     20.4    100
 108     20.6    100
 107     20.8333         100
 106     21      100
 105     21.4    100
 104     21.8    100
 103.5   22      100
```

[image]

**Addition:**

Maybe this is going to the desired direction. I'm not sure whether this is the most efficient way.

**Code:**

```
### plot normalized contour from PNG
reset session

FILE = 'Input.png'

set view map
set size square
set tics out

set table $Dummy
    set contour
    set cntrparam levels 15
    splot FILE binary filetype=png
    unset contour
set table $Contour
    splot $Dummy u 1:2:($3/255) index 1::1
unset table

plot $Contour u 1:2:3 w l lc palette notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right but how can one read those contour level s or the key (which are the same thing essentially) and print them by dividing a const instead of the keys entries itself. Basically the contours are made on an image taken in 255 scale but I want the contour levels to be represent on a normalized scale from 0 to 1. For that I want to divide the keys by 255 and then display the same chart as above but with divided keys..